# How to get all the substrings in string using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, substring

I have a string such as: `"12345"`

using the regex, how to get all of its substrings that consist of one up to three consecutive characters to get an output such as:

```
'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '12', '23', '34', '45', '123', '234', '345'
```

Comment: Why the regex requirement? I believe this will be pretty hard and/or incredibly inefficient

Comment: I'm looking for a way for just give me the result in efficient time, I thought that the Regex may be faster than the traditional 2 for loops.
Did I was wrong by thinking about this approach? and what is the efficient way to solve this problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: Regex would not serve you well in the context of this question as its simply not the tool for the job. Double for-loop, [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), and other tools would serve you better here.

Comment: It is a simple task for `itertools.combinations()`: `[''.join(_) for i in range(1, 4) for _ in itertools.combinations('12345', i)]`

Comment: @accdias thats not quite right as it won't give contiguous substrings. You'll get stuff like `'14' '15` etc.

Comment: Oh! Now I see it. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall` with a positive lookahead pattern that matches a character repeated for a number of times that's iterated from 1 to 3:

```
[match for size in range(1, 4) for match in re.findall('(?=(.{%d}))' % size, s)]
```

However, it would be more efficient to use a list comprehension with nested `for` clauses to iterate through all the sizes and starting indices:

```
[s[start:start + size] for size in range(1, 4) for start in range(len(s) - size + 1)]
```

Given `s = '12345'`, both of the above would return:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '12', '23', '34', '45', '123', '234', '345']
```